# Ubuntu won't update apps or main OS - how can I go back to Windows?

Tags: updates, windows

Nothing happens when I select update, the update just hangs
Both for apps and main OS updates.

I've tried opening terminal and typing

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But i get an error:

```
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

I have this system dual booting with Windows 10, I wish I'd never put it in now.

People keep telling me it runs better, but it wont even update.

Now I am stuck with it anyway, so I try to use it sometimes, but usually have little success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't help at all.
When I try to type in ''sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock'  for example, the code is just repeated but the 'apt' is highlighted in red.

Other question would be, how to uninstall this but keep my windows 10 installation ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zl1Q2UiXu60

That did the trick !

Comment: This is a screenshot of the 4 commands used to get rid of the grub bootloader and replace it with the Windows bootloader in the YouTube video you linked to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrnMl.png Then in the Disk Management application in Windows the Ubuntu partitions were deleted and the Windows partition was extended into the unallocated space that remained after deleting the Ubuntu partitions.

Comment: Thanks, that's the one.
I can't tell you how many times I've tried ubuntu or linux in general, but it lets me down every time.
I will try not to make the mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have this issue?

There was recently a issue with the update servers making it hang, I had the same issue as yours and saw also other reports. Because the update was initiated, the file is locked, so you can't initiate it a second time from the terminal before the first one has released the lock. That's a security a measure.

The server issue seems to be resolved now, your updates should likely therefor just continue being installed.

Server issues like this has never happened to me in the 3 years I've used Ubuntu, so this is for the notice something *very* uncommon.

If you still have this issue it's likely because you aborted a ongoing update, something you should never do on Linux (or Windows for that matter where you just as easy can break your system). On Linux there are luckily many things you can do to fix the system if you still did.

Please check the link to karel and the 2 other answers it links to!

Keep us updated :)

Comment: Rush doesn't have this issue anymore because he deleted Ubuntu and fixed the Windows bootloader: https://askubuntu.com/questions/977714/ubuntu-wont-update-apps-or-main-os#comment1569841_977714 This answer from the second link that I posted includes the steps that Rush followed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on/143482#143482

Comment: OK, what a rush! :P

Comment: You're perfectly welcome! Linux ain't 100% troublefree and I understand your frustration when something do happen, but Windows also got a truckload of issues and that is something people often seems to forget. I hope you will consider Linux again some time. Cheers! <3

Comment: Well, I don't mind what I use, as long as I can use it.
I've tried linux probably around ten times now over ten past ten years.
I just cannot get on with it. I just use what works for me, and linux just doesn't.  Too many terminal commands, not enough software - just not practical.
I may be back in a few years lol.. If they have discovered mouse clicks instead of terminal commands I might give it another go lol

Comment: It's the other way around actually, you don't work with Linux. If you need specific software available only for a certain OS then you should use that OS. But almost always users *think* they need a specific software but they don't as there are equal or better alternatives. You don't need any terminal command to run any major Linux distro but they're really useful and powerful. For the most part you'll be running the same software in the exact same way as in the other OS. But you should never expect Linux to be a drop-in free replacement for Windows, it's just not, it's different and better.